# How to reload table on main queue AFTER looping (Objective-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, memory-management

I am downloading images from the API and storing them asynchonously.  The images are being stored properly, however, they are not being presented on the tableview properly.  What is going on in the code below, is that [self.tableView reloadData]; is being called through each iteration in the loop.  Thus, a lot of the cells are flickering and changing until the last table reload.  How to I make the tableView reload AFTER ALL the images are downloaded, not immediately after every image?  When I put the [self.tableView reloadData] OUTSIDE the dispatch_asynch(dispatch_get_main_queue) function the table never gets refreshed at all.

```
for (int j = 0; j<self.followingArray.count; j++) {

     NSMutableDictionary *following  = (NSMutableDictionary *)[self.followingArray objectAtIndex:j];

            //  Get Images for Users that are following the User
            NSString *followingImage = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[following objectForKey:@"Avatar"]];
            NSString *followingID = followingImage;
            NSString *followingURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://dev-images.stationlocal.com/resize/4/4/49/49/0/0/5/%@",followingID];


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                UIImage *followingAvatarImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:followingURL]]];              
                [following setObject:followingAvatarImage forKey:@"AvatarImage"];

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        // FollowingCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:0]];
                        // [cell.thumbImage setNeedsDisplay];
                        [self.tableView reloadData];
                    });

            });

}
```

Comment: Why don't you just load images individually in each cell? This will simplify your code, and also you won't have to download all images for all cells at the same time, but only for those cells that are currently present on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could really take two approaches.

One is replace [self.tableView reloadData] and individually reload just the row that is affected by the downloaded image.  I'm imagining something like this.

```
for (int j = 0; j<self.followingArray.count; j++) {

     NSMutableDictionary *following  = (NSMutableDictionary *)[self.followingArray objectAtIndex:j];

            //  Get Images for Users that are following the User
            NSString *followingImage = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[following objectForKey:@"Avatar"]];
            NSString *followingID = followingImage;
            NSString *followingURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://dev-images.stationlocal.com/resize/4/4/49/49/0/0/5/%@",followingID];


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                UIImage *followingAvatarImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:followingURL]]];              
                [following setObject:followingAvatarImage forKey:@"AvatarImage"];

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        NSIndexPath* row = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:0];
                        if ( [self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows containsObject:row] ) {
                            FollowingCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:];
                            // update the cell image.
                    });

            });

}
```

or to answer your original question.  You'd need a know when all your images had completed downloading.  Maybe count down a variable as the items load.  e.g.

```
NSInteger remaining = self.followingArray.count;
for (int j = 0; j<self.followingArray.count; j++) {
    NSMutableDictionary *following  = (NSMutableDictionary *)[self.followingArray objectAtIndex:j];

    //  Get Images for Users that are following the User
    NSString *followingImage = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[following objectForKey:@"Avatar"]];
    NSString *followingID = followingImage;
    NSString *followingURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://dev-images.stationlocal.com/resize/4/4/49/49/0/0/5/%@",followingID];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        UIImage *followingAvatarImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:followingURL]]];              
        [following setObject:followingAvatarImage forKey:@"AvatarImage"];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           remaining--;
           if ( remaining <= 0 )
               [self.tableView reloadData];
        });

    });
```

}

Comment: I had to change the if ( ---remaining <= 0) to  (remaining <=0) however.

Comment: Yeah, accidentally decremented it twice.  I corrected it.  Glad it helped.